# ObjectDataSource calling multiple times in nested gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, objectdatasource

I have nested GridView. When I expand row of external it shows internal GridView. Both gridviews are inside UpdatePanel and uses ObjectDataSource to populate data.

When I click on expand, I'm doing a post back by clicking a button via JQuery. Here, ObjectDataSource1 which is for external grid calls SelectMethod multiple times. I checked UpdatePanel UpdateMode is Conditional.

How can I prevent ObjectDataSource from fetching data multiple times?

ASPX:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectCountMethod="GetDevicesCount" SelectMethod="GetDevices" TypeName="Flows" SortParameterName="sortExpression" EnablePaging="True">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtSearch" Name="searchTerm" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="hdnFieldFromDate" Name="fromDate" PropertyName="Value" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="hdnFieldToDate" Name="toDate" PropertyName="Value" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource2" runat="server" SelectCountMethod="GetFlowDetailsCount" SelectMethod="GetFlowDetails" OnSelecting="ObjectDataSource2_Selecting" TypeName="Flows" EnablePaging="True">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="HiddenDeviceId" Name="deviceId" PropertyName="Value" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="hdnFieldFromDate" Name="fromDate" PropertyName="Value" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="hdnFieldToDate" Name="toDate" PropertyName="Value" Type="DateTime" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Comment: see this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479353(d=printer).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have handled this in two ways.

1: In the ASPX side of your page set select method to SelectMethod = "" and assign it if the page is postback.

```
if (Page.IsPostBack)
{
    //Always set the select methods.
    SetSelectMethods();
}
else
{
    ODSGetOptionSearchDataCS.SelectMethod = string.Empty;
    ODSWatchlistCS.SelectMethod = string.Empty;
}    

private void SetSelectMethods()
{
    ODSGetOptionSearchDataCS.SelectMethod = "GetOptionCondors";
    ODSWatchlistCS.SelectMethod = "GetOptionWLCondors";
}
```

2. I really do not care for how I handled this above, so going forward in my select method I cache the data for 10 seconds (longer if I need to) I allow that method to run again, but returned the cached data vs. hitting the database again.